# Is there a difference in the different ways of checking for zombies in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, nszombie, zombie-process

As I understand there are 2 ways of checking for `Zombies` in `Xcode 4`, first is the traditional way of setting `NSZombieEnabled` in the `Environment Variables`, and setting it to "YES", and the other way is `Enabling Zombie Objects` in the `Diagnostics` section of the a scheme.

Is there any difference between these 2 ways?

Thanks
Reza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope no difference they are pretty much the same, checking the checkbox `Enabling Zombie Objects` will make `NSZombieEnabled = YES`

Answer (score 2):

The other way is via Instruments. Cmd-I for Profile action, choose the Zombies instrument. No need to manage the zombies switch manually - the Profile action (Cmd-I) handles this for you.